# How to show data listed in delayed_job log in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job and in a page I am showing all the information related to the job.

listing jobs as:

```
<% @jobs.each do |item| %>   
  <%= item.inspect %> 
<% end %>
```

I am getting details as:

```
#<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 57, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2016-08-30 00:47:46", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, created_at: "2016-08-30 00:47:46", updated_at: "2016-08-30 00:47:46", queue: nil> #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 55, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2016-08-29 09:46:44", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, created_at: "2016-08-29 09:46:44", updated_at: "2016-08-29 09:46:44", queue: nil>
```

With the above data I am able to show the id, priority, attempts etc; But incase of handler, there is a big string consists of object, method_name etc; 
How can I show this handler.object and handler.method_name in rails view? Please help:

This is my handler string:

> --- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer object: !ruby/class 'SubscriptionNotifier' method_name: :welcome args: - !ruby/object:User
>   raw_attributes: deleted_at: name: in test email: intest@test.com
>   encrypted_password:
>   "$2a$10$IUOp.QkdIPauTnVyBRQQXOD0nA.cUc1og/pIEQneBx3nWVY/94Hti" phone:
>   '' website: '' designations: '' id: 25 reset_password_token:
>   reset_password_sent_at: remember_created_at: sign_in_count: '0'
>   current_sign_in_at: last_sign_in_at: current_sign_in_ip:
>   last_sign_in_ip: confirmation_token: created_at: &1 2016-08-30
>   00:47:46.390321885 Z updated_at: *1 contact_id: location: username:
>   photo_file_name: photo_content_type: photo_file_size:
>   photo_updated_at: time_zone: beta_code: account_id: 26 admin: true
>   logo_file_name: logo_content_type: logo_file_size: logo_updated_at:
>   company_name: license_number: spark_id: attributes:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet attributes:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash types: id: &6
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Integer precision: scale: limit:
>   range: !ruby/range begin: -2147483648 end: 2147483648 excl: true
>   email: &2 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::String precision: scale:
>   limit: encrypted_password: *2 reset_password_token: *2
>   reset_password_sent_at: &7
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: &3 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime precision:
>   scale: limit: remember_created_at: &8
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 sign_in_count: &4 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Integer
>   precision: scale: limit: range: !ruby/range begin: -2147483648 end:
>   2147483648 excl: true current_sign_in_at: &9
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 last_sign_in_at: &10
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 current_sign_in_ip: *2 last_sign_in_ip: *2
>   confirmation_token: *2 created_at: &11
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 updated_at: &12
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 contact_id: *4 location: *2 username: *2 photo_file_name:
>   *2 photo_content_type: *2 photo_file_size: *4 photo_updated_at: &13 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 designations: *2 name: *2 phone: *2 website: *2 time_zone:
>   *2 beta_code: *2 account_id: *4 admin: &14 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean precision: scale: limit:
>   deleted_at: &5
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 logo_file_name: *2 logo_content_type: *2 logo_file_size:
>   *4 logo_updated_at: &15 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 company_name: *2 license_number: *2 spark_id: *2 values:
>   id: email: '' encrypted_password: '' reset_password_token:
>   reset_password_sent_at: remember_created_at: sign_in_count: '0'
>   current_sign_in_at: last_sign_in_at: current_sign_in_ip:
>   last_sign_in_ip: confirmation_token: created_at: updated_at:
>   contact_id: location: username: photo_file_name: photo_content_type:
>   photo_file_size: photo_updated_at: designations: name: phone: website:
>   time_zone: beta_code: account_id: admin: f deleted_at: logo_file_name:
>   logo_content_type: logo_file_size: logo_updated_at: company_name:
>   license_number: spark_id: additional_types: {} materialized: true
>   delegate_hash: deleted_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: deleted_at
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *5 value: name:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: name
>   value_before_type_cast: in test type: *2 value: in test email:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: email
>   value_before_type_cast: intest@test.com type: *2 value:
>   intest@test.com encrypted_password:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name:
>   encrypted_password value_before_type_cast:
>   "$2a$10$IUOp.QkdIPauTnVyBRQQXOD0nA.cUc1og/pIEQneBx3nWVY/94Hti" type:
>   *2 value: "$2a$10$IUOp.QkdIPauTnVyBRQQXOD0nA.cUc1og/pIEQneBx3nWVY/94Hti" phone:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: phone
>   value_before_type_cast: '' type: *2 value: '' website:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: website
>   value_before_type_cast: '' type: *2 value: '' designations:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: designations
>   value_before_type_cast: '' type: *2 value: '' id:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: id
>   value_before_type_cast: 25 type: *6 value: 25 reset_password_token:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   reset_password_token value_before_type_cast: type: *2
>   reset_password_sent_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   reset_password_sent_at value_before_type_cast: type: *7
>   remember_created_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   remember_created_at value_before_type_cast: type: *8 sign_in_count:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: sign_in_count
>   value_before_type_cast: '0' type: *4 current_sign_in_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   current_sign_in_at value_before_type_cast: type: *9 last_sign_in_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   last_sign_in_at value_before_type_cast: type: *10 current_sign_in_ip:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   current_sign_in_ip value_before_type_cast: type: *2 last_sign_in_ip:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   last_sign_in_ip value_before_type_cast: type: *2 confirmation_token:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   confirmation_token value_before_type_cast: type: *2 created_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: created_at
>   value_before_type_cast: *1 type: *11 value: *1 updated_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: updated_at
>   value_before_type_cast: *1 type: *12 value: *1 contact_id:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: contact_id
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *4 location:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: location
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *2 username:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: username
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *2 photo_file_name:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   photo_file_name value_before_type_cast: type: *2 value:
>   photo_content_type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
>   name: photo_content_type value_before_type_cast: type: *2 value:
>   photo_file_size: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
>   name: photo_file_size value_before_type_cast: type: *4 value:
>   photo_updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
>   name: photo_updated_at value_before_type_cast: type: *13 time_zone:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: time_zone
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *2 beta_code:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: beta_code
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *2 account_id:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: account_id
>   value_before_type_cast: 26 type: *4 value: 26 admin:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: admin
>   value_before_type_cast: true type: *14 value: true logo_file_name:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   logo_file_name value_before_type_cast: type: *2 value:
>   logo_content_type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
>   name: logo_content_type value_before_type_cast: type: *2 value:
>   logo_file_size: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
>   name: logo_file_size value_before_type_cast: type: *4 value:
>   logo_updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
>   name: logo_updated_at value_before_type_cast: type: *15 company_name:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: company_name
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *2 license_number:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name:
>   license_number value_before_type_cast: type: *2 spark_id:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: spark_id
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *2 new_record: false
>   active_record_yaml_version: 0 - !ruby/object:Account raw_attributes:
>   deleted_at: id: 26 created_at: &16 2016-08-30 00:47:46.181857956 Z
>   updated_at: *16 name: full_domain: attributes:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet attributes:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash types: id: *6 name: *2
>   created_at: &18
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 updated_at: &19
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 full_domain: *2 deleted_at: &17
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
>   subtype: *3 values: id: name: created_at: updated_at: full_domain:
>   deleted_at: additional_types: {} materialized: true delegate_hash:
>   deleted_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name:
>   deleted_at value_before_type_cast: type: *17 value: id:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: id
>   value_before_type_cast: 26 type: *6 value: 26 created_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: created_at
>   value_before_type_cast: *16 type: *18 value: *16 updated_at:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser name: updated_at
>   value_before_type_cast: *16 type: *19 value: *16 name:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: name
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *2 full_domain:
>   !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase name: full_domain
>   value_before_type_cast: type: *2 new_record: false
>   active_record_yaml_version: 0

This is the error log I am getting when I used @kiddorails answer:

> ArgumentError - undefined class/module Account:
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/class_loader.rb:54:in
>   `resolve'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/class_loader.rb:46:in`
>   find'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/class_loader.rb:28:in
>   `load'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:396:in`
>   resolve_class'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:208:in
>   `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`
>   visit'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in
>   `accept'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`
>   accept'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:330:in
>   `block in register_empty'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:330:in`
>   register_empty'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:141:in
>   `visit_Psych_Nodes_Sequence'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`
>   visit'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in
>   `accept'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`
>   accept'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:338:in
>   `block in revive_hash'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`
>   revive_hash'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:374:in
>   `revive'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:208:in`
>   visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in
>   `visit'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in`
>   accept'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in
>   `accept'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:311:in`
>   visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in
>   `visit'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in`
>   accept'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in
>   `accept'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:38:in`
>   to_ruby'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:253:in
>   `load'   app/views/admin/_jobs_table.html.erb:17:in`block in
>   _app_views_admin__jobs_html_erb___466009326523590843_337924780'   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in
>   `each'   app/views/admin/_jobs_table.html.erb:15:in`
>   _app_views_admin__jobs_table_html_erb___466009326523590843_337924780'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in
>   render'

Answer (score 1):

That is yaml format. You need to parse it as following to get the data.

```
job = Delayed::Job.last
data = YAML.load job.handler # parse the yaml
puts data.method_name #=> :welcome args
puts data.object #=> Delayed::PerformableMailer
```

You can iterate like:

```
<% @jobs.each do |item| %>   
  <% data = YAML.load item.handler %> 
  <%= item.id %>
  <%= data.method_name %>
  <%= data.object %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is showing error as: **ArgumentError: undefined class/module Account** and I will show log in my question. Please check,

Comment: I think some of your job object has `Account` class in it's handler while you probably don't have Account model.

Comment: As shown in the above handler log, I am having account_id in it. I am having Account model too.

Comment: try my first snippet in rails console. Does it return the same thing?